# Is it possible to automatically attach to a tmux session using Chrome's Secure Shell extension?

Tags: google-chrome, ssh, terminal, google-chrome-extensions, tmux

Using [Secure Shell](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/secure-shell/pnhechapfaindjhompbnflcldabbghjo) in Chrome, can you *automatically* attach to a tmux session when SSH-ing to a server? If so, how do you do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `.bashrc` file you should be able to call `tmux attach` on the server.  A line like this is the last line of my `.bashrc' file and it works fine.

This of course requires that a session exists on the server at the point when you secure shell into it and that you are using `bash`.